# after submitting JSP form display result on same page

Tags: forms, jsp, submit

I am facing a problem in my Jsp page. I am filling the values in form and then clicking on Submit button. Now the problem which I am facing is, that I want the filled values to be shown in that division only in which I filled the form. I don’t want values/result of form to be displayed in next page.

My code of form is this:

```
<FORM id="Fid" METHOD="GET" ACTION="attributesWithModelInfo.jsp">
<INPUT NAME="make" TYPE="hidden" value="<%=(String) session.getAttribute("baseMake")%>"/><BR> <!--  This attribute is optional and can be used as a regular expression. -->
<INPUT NAME="model" TYPE="hidden" value="<%=(String) session.getAttribute("baseModel")%>"/><BR> <!--  This attribute is optional and can be used as a regular expression. -->
<INPUT NAME="year" TYPE="hidden" value="<%=(String) session.getAttribute("baseYear")%>"/><BR> <!--  This attribute is optional and can be used as a regular expression. -->

Attribute Name: <INPUT NAME="attribute" TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="30"/><BR>
Attribute Name: <INPUT NAME="attribute" TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="30"/><BR>
Attribute Name: <INPUT NAME="attribute" TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="30"/><BR>
Attribute Name: <INPUT NAME="attribute" TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="30"/><BR>
Attribute Name: <INPUT NAME="attribute" TYPE="TEXT" SIZE="30"/><BR>
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT">
</FORM>
```

Code of ajax that I am trying is:

```
$(function() {
 alert('here I am in Attribute');
    $("#Fid").submit(function(e) {

    var name = $("#attribute").val();
    var dataString = 'attribute='+ attribute;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "attributesWithModelInfo.jsp",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(){
        }
        });
    e.preventDefault();
        });
```

return false;
            });

The form is in attributesWithModelInfo.jsp file.
This file is given its href in index.jsp as:

```
<li><a href="attributesWithModelInfo.jsp" id="pageurls">Attributes</a></li>
```

The div in which Form is displayed and the result after submit too has to be displayed is:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a#pageurls').on("click", function(){  
            $("#refdiv").load($(this).attr("href"));
            return false;
        });
    });
```

the upper code too is in index.jsp

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer your question if you posted some code...

Comment: The first problem I see is that your javascript is getting the value of an element with ID `attribute`, but your form does not have such an element.  Try using jquery's serialize() on the whole form to get all values.  `var datastring = $('#Fid').serialize();`

Comment: I want to show a table which I am getting from another jsp page after submit in the same div in which the form is.
After your changes no doubt I am on the same div but it is displaying my complete HTML code in that div instead of "dataString" value.